# Wordpress php while loop to return a page by id

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with this query- I just want to get a single page so I can use  etc.

Currently, I am getting this error:

***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in***

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query('page_id='79); while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's your problem:

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query('page_id='79); while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                                        ^
```

Change it to this:

```
'page_id=79'
```

Comment: Wow, cant believe I didnt notice that, was looking at it for ages too :-( Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that this:

```
'page_id='79
```

Should be

```
'page_id=79'
```

Note the position of the last `'`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `wp_query` in `while` loop? If you have the id and want a single page, just use `get_page( $page_id )`